# How do you free an XMLHttpRequest object, and how to do you free a ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") object?

Tags: javascript

How do you free an XMLHttpRequest object, and how to do you free a ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") object?

Grae

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the reference to `null` should free up the memory.

Comment: I think null should work that best, because delete does extra work.  I just want the object to get deletes as needed.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) you **do not** have to explicitly free objects. You *could* use `delete variableThatHoldTheObject` or `variableThatHoldTheObject = null` but that will only decrease the reference count of the object by `1`.

There might be still other references to the object. So in short, leave it to the GC to handle this for you, since you can't force it anyways.

**Concerning you Comment**

`delete` will remove the variable and therefore the reference to the object it was pointing to.

```
var foo = 4;
foo; // 4
foo = null;
foo; // null
delete foo;
foo; // ReferenceError
```

Still, that only decreases the reference count by 1. The GC will not collect the object until its reference count reached 0. So in case there a `bar` somewhere that still points to the object, it won't get collected.

Comment: What is the difference between delete and setting the object to null?

Comment: Setting it to `null` will simply set the value of the variable to null, `delete` will remove the variable itself. I'll update my answer with a small example.

Comment: I think for my purposes I am better of just setting the variable to null.  That is the fastest best solution.